# Is it possible that part of the subject is an adjective in the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I came upon a sentence I can’t grasp in a text book.

The sentence is the following

> What so often happens is that either that day or over time, less and less is kept,
> first of winnings and then of the sum originally slated for wagering.

I know that an inversion is used in a subordinate clause. So the subject is “first of
Winnings and then of the sum originally slated for wagering”.

Here I can’t understand the phrase “then of”

I think the part of speech of “then” might be an adjective. Is it possible that part of the subject is an adjective in the sentence.

Comment: It seems to be about gambling. Over time, the gambler gets to keep less and less money - at first, they start to keep less of their winnings, and _then_ [less] of the sum they gambled with.

Comment: The text as written wouldn't be particularly unusual as a ***spoken*** utterance, but I'd strongly recommend rephrasing to make it easier to parse as a ***written*** text. It's not a good example for deconstructing into traditional named "parts of speech" (even for *linguists and grammarians* - I certainly can't see that as a useful exercise for non-native Anglophone *learners*).

Comment: No: the subject is the noun phrase "what so often happens" ("that which so often happens"). "Then" is best analysed as a preposition: we understand “first, less and less is kept of the winnings, and then (less and less is kept) of the sum originally slated for wagering.

Answer (score 1):

In the given sentence, the subject is *"What so often happens"* and  here *'then'* is not an adjective, but it's an *adverbial conjunction* or a *'conjunctive adverb'*.

Conjunctive adverbs are adverbials that connect words, phrases, and sentences together. They are used to shorten sentences also. Most of all, they help in *'transition from one topic to another'.*

Comment: Modern grammar calls this "then" a preposition because it means "after that". [link](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/then)